# Vim search for a pattern and if occurs delete to end of line

Tags: regex, vim

I am trying to search a text file for a certain pattern.  If this pattern occurs then it means that the rest of the line is not needed and therefore can be deleted.

I have tried using the following commands, but so far have been unsuccessful.

```
:%s/{pattern}/d$

:g/{pattern}/d$
```

If anyone has any suggestions they would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 82, accepted):

would `:%s/{pattern}.*//` work?

Comment: I tried the following to delete everything after \\ in the following line on the entire file.  Example line containing: test black brown blue \\c\d\k - - :%s/\\.*//

Comment: shouldn't it be ` :%s/\\\\.*//` (the backslash needs to be backslashed)

Comment: that was my thought too, but interestingly it works. your solution works as well. Tested it.

Comment: your version deletes everything after a single backslash, so yes it works to delete everything after a double one. It may delete things you don't want to delete though

Comment: I am starting trying vim again and this just blow up my mind

Answer (score 40):

Alternatively, the following also works

```
:g/{pattern}/normal nd$
```

For what you want, I would go with mirod's suggestion. What I posted is a bit more flexible and might come in handy in similar situations.

Explanation:

On each line, where pattern matches, execute the following normal mode commands 'nd$'. With the cursor at the start of the line, 'n' jumps to the pattern, and 'd$' deletes to the end of the line.

Comment: You can also use `norm nD` since `D` is synonymous with `d$`.

Answer (score 3):

To replace a pattern and whatever else use the regular expression wild card `.*`

```
:1,$s/pattern.*//g
```

Answer (score -1):

```
%s/\\(replay-pattern-later\\) pattern2/\1/gc
```

This will replay pattern1 but eliminate pattern2.  Using "/gc" to apply globally (keep going) and prompt for each occurence.