# Vim search for a pattern and if NOT occurs delete line

Tags: vim, filter

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569280/vim-search-for-a-pattern-and-if-occurs-delete-to-end-of-line) question, but I want to know how can I delete the line when the pattern DOESN'T occur.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Deleting the rest of the line when a pattern does not occur is **...** hard for me to understand.

Did you mean, delete the whole line if it doesn't have a pattern?

```
:v/pattern/d
```

If you meant, preserve the line but clobber the characters:

```
:v/pattern/s/.*//
```

Comment: And yes, I mean delete the whole line

Answer (score 6):

Equivalently:

```
:g!/pattern/d
```

Easier to remember in my opinion, because`!` is ingrained as "not" in my brain.

Answer (score 1):

```
:v/pattern/s/.*//
```